# Android async task reads json data from website and fills listview (too slow)

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have a question about async tasks and collecting data through HTTPReaders. I am making a small android application with Android Studio which has a local SQLLite database and uses an API to collect additional data.

So I have this local data (store which has a name and village object) and external json data (village which has a zip code and name). So I would like to fill in a `ListView` with the store's name and between brackets the village's name. The problem is that when I call the HTTPReader, it loads to slow so my village's name has loaded but between the brackets is null. I want to wait until all the data is loaded and then display it, how can I do this?

I collect the village's Json data from an external website. I use an httpReader with an result ready listener. When I have my data I decode json and send an array list of objects to my `ListViewAdapter` which fills the

`Store` class:

```
public class Store implements Serializable {
private int id;
private String name;
private Village village= new Village();

public Store() {
}

public Store(int id, String name, Village village) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.village= village;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Village getVillage() {
    return village;
}

public void setVillage(Village village {
    this.village = village;
}


@Override
public String toString()
{
    return this.getName() + " (" + this.getVillage().getName() + ')';
}

public void setJsonVillageByID(int id)
{
    HttpReader httpReader = new HttpReader();
    httpReader.setOnResultReadyListener(new HttpReader.OnResultReadyListener() {
        @Override
        public void resultReady(String result) {
            JsonHelper jsonHelper = new JsonHelper();
            setVillage(jsonHelper.getVillage(result));
        }
    });
    httpReader.execute("http://storevillages.com/villages?search=id&value=" + id);
}}
```

Method for filling in the listview:

```
 private void fillListViewStores() {

    ArrayList<Store> stores = dbHelper.getStores();
    ListView listViewStores = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.stores_listViewStores);


    ArrayAdapter<Store> listViewStoresAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Store>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, stores);


    listViewStores.setAdapter(listViewStoresAdapter);
}
```

Database getStore:

```
    public Store getStore(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(
            "Store",     
            new String[]{"id", "name", "villageID"}, 
            "id = ?",  
            new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, 
            null,           // groupby
            null,           // having
            null,           // sorting
            null);          // ??

    Store store = new Store();
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        store.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
        store.setName(cursor.getString(1));
        store.setJsonVillageByID(cursor.getInt(2));
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return store;
}
```

So I want to wait to fill in the spinner until all the villages has been loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to restructure your code so that `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` can be called when the village value is set from the `HttpReader` data.

Maybe something like this would work:

```
private void fillListViewStores() {

    ArrayList<Store> stores = dbHelper.getStores();
    final ArrayAdapter<Store> listViewStoresAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Store>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, stores);

    for (Store s : stores) {
        final Store store = s;
        HttpReader httpReader = new HttpReader();
        httpReader.setOnResultReadyListener(new HttpReader.OnResultReadyListener() {
            @Override
            public void resultReady(String result) {
                JsonHelper jsonHelper = new JsonHelper();
                store.setVillage(jsonHelper.getVillage(result));
                listViewStoresAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        httpReader.execute("http://storevillages.com/villages?search=id&value=" + store.getId());
    }

    ListView listViewStores = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.stores_listViewStores);
    listViewStores.setAdapter(listViewStoresAdapter);
}
```